# Meteor - Filter a Collection at template level subscription?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Currently I have a template which subscribes to a collection:

```
Template.Actividades.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        self.subscribe("recursos");
    });
});

Template.Actividades.helpers({
    recursos: function() {
        return Recursos.find({clase: "Actividades"});
    }
});
```

unfortunately when I do the find({}) with the condition I still get all the items in the collection to display and not just the ones that have "Actividades" as the "clase".

Below is the Collection Schema relevant to this part:

```
RecursosSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  clase: {
    type: String,
    label: "Clase",
    allowedValues: ["Actividades", "Colegios", "Jardines"],
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        firstOption: "(Selecciona una clase)"
      }
    }
  },
```

Question is what am I doing wrong in the find({}) condition?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: are you sure this is returning all the items? go to your browser console and run this exact query `Recursos.find({clase: "Actividades"}).fetch()`
and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed, the incorrect code was at the iterating template level.

Thanks for the help.